# Como centralizar um H3 com background-color?

Tags: css, html5

Como posso deixar centralizado esse H3 com o background-color?

já tentei de tudo, procurei na internet mas não achei uma solução

```
    <style>
        h3 {
        background-color:#98FB98;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-width: 1px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        color: gray;
        }       
    </style>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vrmj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troca o `margin-top: 10px` por `margin: 10px auto 1em auto;`.

Elementos de bloco, quando menores que a largura do viewport, tiverem margin auto nas laterais, eles se centralizam horizontalmente. O `margin` com 4 valores já definem as 4 direções na ordem `top right bottom left`:

```
        top      bottom
         ↓         ↓
margin: 10px auto 1em auto;
              ↑        ↑
            right    left
```

O valor `1em` é o valor padrão do *user agent* (navegador)

Veja:

```css
h3 {
   background-color:#98FB98;
   margin: 10px auto 1em auto;
   width: 20%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-width: 1px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
   color: gray;
}
```

```html
<h3>texto</h3>
```

Comment: Show cara! 
agora eu entendi

Comment: Sou iniciante
comecei estudar apouco tempo